# How to center and stretch an image when calling element.requestFullscreen() on a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullscreen

I am really new to **CSS** and **HTML** and I am afraid I do not understand this problem:

I have an image inside an anchor tag. In the `onclick` event I put the outer `div` in fullscreen. The `div` contains next / previous buttons for a slideshow.

The problem is, when the fullscreen method is called, the image is not resized nor centered which both is what I want to achieve.

Here follows the HTML code:

```html
                <div id="container" class="grpelem">
                        <!-- stack box -->
                        <div id="slideshow">
                            <!-- image -->
                            <div class="slide0">
                                <div class="numbertext">1 / 1</div>
                                <a href="javascript:;" onclick=" fullScreen(document.getElementById('container')) "><img id="dsc03837" alt="" src="images/schulhaus/dsc03837.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1,0)">❮</a>
                            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1,0)">❯</a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /m_editable -->
                    </div>          
                </div>
```

Here follows the CSS code:

```css
    .grpelem 
    {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
    }

    #container {
        z-index: 530;
        fit-position:auto;
        max-width:100%;
        max-height:100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    #slideshow{
        z-index: 544;
        border-width: 0px;
        border-color: transparent;
        background-color: #4F4F4F;
        border-radius: 10px;
        max-width:100%;
        max-height:100%;
        display:flex;
    }

    #dsc03837 {
        max-width:100%;
        max-height:100%;
    }
```

Here follows the JS fullscreen script:

```js
    let slideIndex = [1];
    let slideId = ["slide0"];
    showSlides(1, 0);

    function plusSlides(n, no) {
      showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
    }

    function showSlides(n, no) {
      let i;
      let x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
      if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         x[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
    }

    function fullScreen(element) 
    {
        if (document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement ||
            document.mozFullScreenElement)
        {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        }
        else if (element.requestFullscreen) 
        {
            element.requestFullscreen();
        } 
        else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) 
        {
            element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        } 
        else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) 
        {
            element.mozRequestFullScreen();
        }
    }
```

The behaviour I do not understand: I put the `id=slideshow` to be `100% max-width`. The next and prev buttons are displayed correctly to the middle left and middle right. The image in the same `div` is displayed on the top left in fullscreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

max-width, max-height was the wrong option in this case. i had to use the variant without "max-".